# I want a regex that will select all characters including special characters, except the Last 4 Characters. Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let str = "AAAAA-0000021111-1111"; 
let res = str.match(/\d(?=\d{4})/g);
document.write(res);
```

//This didnt work, the output is given below:

Output:
0,0,0,0,0,2

// its only selecting these characters which are highlighted in bold AAAAA-**000002**1111-1111

And this is what I am expecting:

A,A,A,A,A,-,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,-

Basically, I want all characters to be selected including - or any other special characters **except the last 4.**

I am listing a couple of extra samples for a better understanding

Sample1: ABC-101010-1111
Expected output is: A,B,C,-,1,0,1,0,1,0,-

Sample2: ABCD101010-11111
Expected output is: A,B,C,D,1,0,1,0,1,0,-,1

I am using Vanilla JS.

Really appreciate your involvement in this.

Thanks in Advance Sir/Ma'am!!!

Comment: You told it to match a digit that's immediately followed by 4 digits. Why should it match a letter?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I've mentioned that I want all chars to be selected including special chars except last 4 chars, I am sorry I typed in a hurry, but however I have given samples that are very clear, Thanks for your involvement Barmar

Comment: What you want is clear. Why did you think that a regexp that only matches `\d` would achieve it?

Comment: You're supposed to make a sincere attempt to solve the problem and post that attempt here. Your attempt doesn't even come close to matching what you want.

Comment: No, `\d` doesn't match letters. That's why you only got numbers in your result.

Comment: Barmar, I am sorry that regex with \d was accepting all the characters without the hiffen (-). Ex: AAAAA1111111111 and the op would be XXXXXXXXXXX1111 for the old regex that I've mentioned in my post. But then my req. was updated. I have to deal with special characters too. Also I am a noob when it comes to typing regex and I also dont know how to edit a regex. Only after seeing comment, I googled for it and came to know what \d actually does! Hope this answered your queries Barmar.

Comment: Just add a comment if u want to discuss anything

Comment: I don't want to discuss anything. I was just pointing out why your basic approach was in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get better soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231185/discussion-between-siva-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?!\d{1,4}$)./g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbJBWH/1).

NOTE: If you need to match all chars except last four *any* chars, you will need to replace `\d` with `.` in the lookahead, and it can be even written in a bit more succint way:

```js
/.(?!.{0,3}$)/g
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbJBWH/2).

*Details*:

- `.` - any single char other than line break char
- `(?!.{0,3}$)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location not immediately followed with zero to three chars other than line break chars, till end of string.

The regex will match any char other than a line break char (`.`, to match line breaks, use `[^]`, `[\s\S]`/`[\d\D]`/`[\w\W]` or add `s` flag) that does not start a sequence of one, two, three or four digits at the end of string (`(?!\d{1,4}$)`).

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
console.log("AAAAA-0000021111-1111".match(/(?!\d{1,4}$)./g))
console.log("AAAAA-0000021111-1111".match(/.(?!.{0,3}$)/g))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Wiktor!!
I haven't tested this yet, but I have a good confidence in your regex will try it and let you know, Thanks Again